# Non booting, storage only MBR discs and UEFI

Tags: uefi, mbr

I have Windows 7 SP1 64bit installed on a 500Gb GPT formatted disc and a UEFI booting configured PC. Can I install ***three 1Tb each*** storage only MBR formatted discs in this system? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure, absolutely. The disks are each independent, and MBR can support 1 TB no problem. They're just SATA devices at that point, the UEFI doesn't really care what's on them - the OS handles that bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you aren't using them for booting it won't matter much what partition scheme they use. In fact, depending on your BIOS you might still be able to boot from them using the old legacy boot method (if they had something bootable on them). In a well functioning system adding them to your system will not impair it in any way.

That said, you can quite easily convert them to GPT partition scheme from within Windows. Go to `Start`, type `Computer Management` (directly into the start menu), then right click on Computer Management and choose `Run as Administrator`. Then, on the left side, go to `Disk Management`.

You should see your newly installed HDDs listed in the top and a partition map shown at the bottom. In the partition map it will list the drives by number (Disk 0, Disk 1, Disk 2, etc). If you right click on the gray part near where it says "disk #" for the new drives there should be an option to `Convert to GPT Disk`. You may have to unmount all partitions on that disk first (remove their drive letters) if the option is grayed out. See image to help find the option.

[image: Convert to GPT Disk Screen Shot]

Comment: The last I checked, the procedure you describe will cause any data on the disks to be lost. This may be fine (it's not clear from the question if Walt needs to preserve existing data on the disks), but if not, I want to make that clear. Some third-party tools, including my own [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/), can do a lossless MBR-to-GPT conversion.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that info from. I have done this several times in Windows 7 and 8 and I never lost data. It's possible something has changed in Windows 10? Have not done this on 10 yet. That said, I have nothing against using third party tools for those who are more comfortable doing so. I've used gdisk myself when doing this from GNU Linux.